# I stopped receiving tag filter subscription notification emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification, subscription

I'm not receiving tag filter subscription email notifications anymore.

I did not change configuration of my subscriptions (https://stackexchange.com/users/3089209/xmojmr?tab=subscriptions) and I did not change configuration of my e-mail account.

Last mails I received were from July 24, 2018. No more emails since then. I have checked my spam folder. Everything worked fine for several years until now.

How can I troubleshoot the problem? Should I re-subscribe?

Comment: Same for me. No notification in last few days. I've even tried to re-subscribe. While I get *"Confirm your filter subscription"* email and I confirmed it, I receive no more notification after that.

Comment: Me too: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313245/ive-had-no-email-notifications-for-3-days

Comment: @MichaelKay you removed your question...

Comment: This was my question: I've had no email notifications for 3 days. There have definitely been questions on my filtered tags. They're not in the spam bucket. What should I do?

Until 11:02 on 24 July I was getting regular emails every 3 hours, with very occasional gaps when there was nothing to report.

I asked for a new confirmation email to be sent and it arrived immediately, so the site is capable of sending me email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371671/871146) this was just fixed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Well, it appears to be broken again, didn't get email since October 4th.

Comment: Another example which suggests that are are some problems are the comments of the poster of this question (MathOverflow Meta): [Tag subscriptions and “Watch tag”](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3910). (As I did not have email subscription prior changing Favorite tags to Tag watching, I don't have a possibility to test this for myself.)

Comment: I can confirm that the emails stopped since October 4th. Here's a report from another user on Meta.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375089/email-subscriptions-for-tags-not-being-delivered?noredirect=1#comment636760_375089

Comment: @ShadowWizard some residual issues from our migration to EF Core. tl;dr: lazy loading was sometimes failing because ORMs are intrinsically evil. Fix is out and emails will get sent out over the coming hours. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Martin see comment above

Comment: @defaultlocale see comment above

Comment: Thanks, got email few hours ago.